# Aptana Studio 3 embedded terminal using wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, version, aptana

I just installed ruby 1.9.3 with pik on Windows 7.

When I run ruby -v in a cmd prompt, I get back ruby version 1.9.3 as expected. But when I run ruby -v in the embedded terminal in Aptana Studio 3, I get back 1.9.2.

**How can I get the embedded terminal to use ruby 1.9.3?**

I assume it has something to do with the fact that it is cygwin or something like that because it can run curl and other commands cmd.exe cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your terminal separately. Because it's different from windows. Use Linux commands to update your terminal in aptana.